# Freezing blue cheese

Tags: freezing, cheese

I've been told you can freeze blue cheese. I would like to freeze some for Christmas Day, in one month's time.

What would be the best way to prepare/wrap it and then thaw it to best preserve its texture and flavour? Is there anything I should avoid doing?

I intend to use Stilton, possibly Saint Agur also, but would anything else work better?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I cannot claim to know the "best" way, but I freeze various cheeses all the time, mostly cheddar but including stilton.  I buy them wrapped in airtight plastic wrappers, leave them in them and freeze on day of purchase.  I defrost them in the fridge over a day or so before I open the packet.  It is pretty much indistinguishable from  freshly bought.